# How would I fix this code to make each card into an object?

Tags: javascript

I have this program that creates different cards(From nine to Ace) in every suit(Heart, Diamonds, Clubs, Spades) but I would like each card to become an object so that I may access each cards suit and value.

```
    //This part of the code creates the card, this is what I will need to change.
    function card (name , suit) { 
        window.cardsuit = suit;
        window.cardname = name;
    }

    //This is the deck object it contains the code for making the deck
var deck = {
    //The list of suits
    suit: suits = ["Diamond", "Heart", "Club", "Spade"],
    //The list of card names
    name: names = ["Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"],
    //Array of cards
    cards: cards = [],
    //This function repeats to create each card
    createcards: function(){
            for (var i = 0; i < suits.length; i++){
                for (var j = 0; j < names.length; j++){
                    card(names[j], suits[i]);
                    deck.cards.push(window.cardname + window.cardsuit);



            }
        }
    },

    //This function is used later on to draw a card randomly from the deck
    draw: function (player){
        var randnumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * deck.cards.length));
        player.push(deck.cards[randnumber]);
        deck.cards.splice(randnumber, 1);
    }
};

    //Object of the player hands
    var hand = {
        //This deals out the players hands
        dealhands: function dealhands(amount) {
        t = 0;
        var player_one = [];
        var player_two = [];
        var player_three = [];
        var player_four = [];
        var kitty = [];
        //Deals it however many times I would like the cards dealt
        while (t < amount){
            deck.draw(player_one);
            deck.draw(player_two);
            deck.draw(player_three);
            deck.draw(player_four);
            deck.draw(kitty);
            alert(player_one[0]);
            t ++;
        }
    }

    };
```

I believe I need to use the "this" keyword, but I have no idea how to use it in this context. Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To define a "class" (javascript does not have classes, it is prototypal, but "class" is a helpful word to describe it):

```
function Card (rank , suit) { 
    this.suit = suit;
    this.rank = rank;
}

var ace_of_spades = new Card('A','♠');
deck.cards.push(ace_of_spades);
```

Otherwise you're looking good here. The term for "name" is technically called a "rank" in cards, so I changed those variable names.

You're creating global variables here, which is bad:

```
suit: suits = ["Diamond", "Heart", "Club", "Spade"],
//The list of card names
name: names = ["Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"],
//Array of cards
cards: cards = [],
```

Keep it as :

```
suit: ["Diamond", "Heart", "Club", "Spade"],
//The list of card names
ranks: ["Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"],
//Array of cards
cards: [],
```